# Changing background image, fades out old image twice then fades in new one

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.active-bean-bag ul li').hover(function() { 
    var activeBeanBag = 'menu-' + $(this).attr("class");
    $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeOut();
    $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeIn(function(){
            $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').attr("src", '/images/'+activeBeanBag+'.png');
    });
});
```

However when I hover over a different `LI` it looks like it fades out twice on the old images so out and in and then out a gain then fades into the new image? Any ideas why?

UPDATED:

```
$('.active-bean-bag ul li').mouseover(function() { 
    var activeBeanBag = 'menu-' + $(this).attr("class");
    var newImage = '/skins/temaplate/customer/images/'+activeBeanBag+'.png';
    var $img = $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image');
    if ($img.attr('src') != newImage) {
        $img.fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", newImage).fadeIn();
        });
    }
});​
```

ALSO TRIED WITH SAME RESULT:

```
$(".active-bean-bag ul li").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var activeBeanBag = 'menu-' + $(this).attr("class");
    $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeOut(400, function() {
                $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').attr('src','/skins/template/customer/images/'+activeBeanBag+'.png');
        }).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: Could you please share a JSFiddle example where we can see the problem?

Comment: i have made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XPthr/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are running simultaneously, fighting over the opacity. 
Instead, chain your `fadeIn()` call to the callback of `fadeOut()`:

```
$('.active-bean-bag ul li').hover(function() { 
var activeBeanBag = 'basn0g' + $(this).attr("class");
$('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeOut(function(){
    $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').attr("src", 'http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/'+activeBeanBag+'.png');
    $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeIn();
});
```

});​

as in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XPthr/5/ . (I also changed the `src` assignment to before the `fadeIn()` so that it fades in with the new image visible.

Comment: i think it does the previous image of the previous hover if that makes sense

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Are you seeing it in the fiddle or in your own code? Here is a fiddle with the images inline: http://jsfiddle.net/XPthr/6/ . The correct image shows when hovering.

Comment: It cannot catch up if you go over them quickly as it is a menu - seems to be 1 behind all the time, however if you hover over one wait for the change go of the li then on to the next with a delay in doing so in between it works.

Comment: if you have a look here on this dev environment: http://tinyurl.com/bjsyrtg - hover over "our collection" and then the options in there and you will see what i mean.

Comment: I see what you mean. It looks like its fading in before the new image has finished loading. Try calling the .fadeIn() from the .load() event  like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XPthr/8/ .  I wrapped the fadeOut() in a conditional because the load() event doesn't fire if the `src` has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.active-bean-bag ul li').mouseover(function() { 
    var activeBeanBag = 'basn0g' + $(this).attr("class");
    var newImage = 'http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/'+activeBeanBag+'.png';
    var $img = $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image');
    if ($img.attr('src') != newImage) {
        $img.fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", newImage).fadeIn();
        });
    }
});​
```

Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/grantman16/XPthr/4/

When you use hover with just one parameter, you bind your function to both the mouseenter and mouseleave events. That's why it faded out twice. See the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: I tried on my original example but does not seem to work, i changed a few bits around such as classes as the j sfiddle was a quick made up version - added code in main question can you see what ive done wrong?

Comment: just looked and site is using 1.5.2 jquery

Comment: Your code looks ok. Can you explain what exactly is going wrong?